# How can I make a condition with current_user in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm a freshman to learn Rails and working on my first project about online book writing.

I've already made the MVC of user,book and section. I wanna create a button called "Author Place",which can show all the pieces written by the current logged in user.

I wanna ask a simple question. How can I make a condition with the current username to select the current author's works from the book database. Should I put this code in controller or view?

Code as follow.

`current_user` method of the ApplicationController:

```
protect_from_forgery
helper_method :current_user

private
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

The Section model :

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :book_id, :section_content, :section_tag, :user_username
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The Section controller :

```
class SectionsController < ApplicationController
  def userpieces
    @sections=Section.find(:all, :conditions=>"user_username=current_user.username") # This part doesn't work
  end
end
```

Or any suggestions with some other way to do this?

Comment: Which version of Rails is this?

Comment: If you've set up your relationships properly you should never have to manually do something like this. Check out @depa's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a corresponding `has_many :sections` association in your `User` model, try this:

```
@sections = current_user.sections
```

Comment: @su-jiang @depa here assumes the User model has the inverse `has_many :sections` association.

Comment: Yup. As he/she should.

Comment: Duly noted and included in answer. /nod

Comment: Yes,I have a association has_many : section in user model. Thank you guys,this problem is solved now.

Comment: That's good to know! Don't forget to choose the answer as the correct one if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

As depa and izuriel mentioned, you should be able to get it simply if your model relation is correctly set.

Anyway, if you wish to get it in the way you try please use:

```
@sections=Section.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_username= ?",current_user.username])
```

Please note, in rails 3, .find(:all is deprecated, please use .all instead.